# What markup languages are typically used for annotating information extraction corpora

Tags: nlp, information-extraction

I'm building a corpus for information extraction for extracting specific types of information, and I'm trying to decide the best way to annotate the entities.  I have found that the IEER corpus uses SGML tag elements `ENAMEX`, `NUMEX`, and `TIMEX` tags for this (as described here: http://itl.nist.gov/iaui/894.02/related_projects/muc/proceedings/ne_task.html).  Since this document was written in 1997, I'm guessing that using this SGML-based approach is quite out of date, and there must be better ways of doing this, e.g. using OWL, RDF, or XML. Is there a more recent industry standard for annotating information extraction corpora?

Comment: I would go with XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say there isn't enough standardisation in the field but also it is not clear if there needs to be a single format. My advice is to look at the options and choose the one that fits best your data and the information you are encoding.

[brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/) is the new classic in terms of annotating language resources. It has it's own standoff annotation standard. There is also the [Anafora](https://github.com/weitechen/anafora) tool which also has it's own XML-based standard. The UIMA-based tools usually use a CAS standard (but bad documentation). You should also look at the native [GATE XML format](https://gate.ac.uk/sale/tao/splitch5.html).

If the information you are encoding is simple enough, like say named entity types, you can even go for a tabular format such as [CoNLL](http://www.cnts.ua.ac.be/conll2000/chunking/).

If none of those fits your requirements, simply implement whatever does fit them.

Answer (score 1):

The NLTK book ([chapter 07, paragraph: Representing Chunks: Tags vs Trees](http://www.nltk.org/book_1ed/ch07.html)) states:

> The most widespread file representation uses **IOB tags**.

and goes on to explain:

> [...]  each token is tagged with one of three special chunk tags, I (inside), O (outside), or B (begin). [...] The B and I tags are suffixed with the chunk type, e.g. B-NP, I-NP
>
> ```
> We PRP B-NP
> saw VBD O
> the DT B-NP
> little JJ I-NP
> yellow JJ I-NP
> dog NN I-NP
> ```

Wikipedia has a page on the [IOB format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_Outside_Beginning).

Stanford NLP [apparently](https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/LabeledChunkIdentifier.html) supports it too.

spaCy uses the slightly different [BILUO format](https://alpha.spacy.io/docs/api/annotation#biluo).